# 3D Plot show wrong axis labels (X-axis has Y-axis name and Y-axis has X-axis name)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to creat 3D histogram but I have no idea why X-axis has Y-label and Y-axis has X-axis. What is wrong?

```
xAmplitudes = ([0 for i, j in zip(x, width)])
yAmplitudes = centre_y 

x = np.array(xAmplitudes)   #turn x,y data into numpy arrays
y = np.array(yAmplitudes)

fig = plt.figure()          #create a canvas, tell matplotlib it's 3d
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


#make histogram stuff - set bins - I choose 50x50 because I have a lot of data
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(50,50))
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+xedges[1:], yedges[:-1]+yedges[1:])

xpos = xpos.flatten()/2.
ypos = ypos.flatten()/2.
zpos = np.zeros_like (xpos)

dx = xedges [1] - xedges [0]
dy = yedges [1] - yedges [0]
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=blue, zsort='average')
plt.xlabel("X ")
plt.ylabel("Y ")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note what the [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) documentation says concerning the output array:

> "The bi-dimensional histogram of samples x and y. Values in x are histogrammed along the first dimension and values in y are histogrammed along the second dimension."

This means you would want to transpose the resulting array, probably like

```
dz = hist.T.flatten()
```